# Soft: Interesting examples of applications of the Itô–Nisio theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, soft-question, banach-spaces

I'm writing up a presentation on the Itô–Nisio theorem and I'm looking for a simple (nontrivial) example showcasing it.  I was thinking of a 2-dimensional simple random walk, but that seems uninteresting, any thoughts or suggestions (references are always appreciated).